# Woocommerce product and category can not show up after moving to new domain

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I really need your help, guys:

Recently I've decided to move my old Wordpress site to new domain. The old domain still accessible though.

I cloned old site to new domain along with it's image and database.

Everything run smoothly except one: woocommerce.

It can not display product or category for non logged in user.
Everytime I manually access the product category URL, it redirected to homepage.

It just can't show the product/category for non-logged in user.
I've tried to re-install the woocommerce, but have no luck.

Maybe you, Guys have an Idea about this.

Any help would really be appreciated.

I'm using the latest Wordpress, Woocommerce and Avada theme.

Comment: Have you tried to deactivate all other plugins except for woocommerce? Also you can try to change to permalink to standard to see if you can access them, or re-save the permalinks

Comment: Well, you saved my life!
It gives me clear idea what the problem really is.

The problem is in WP Support Plus. The page for support page wasn't set yet and somehow it affect role in woocommerce product/category display.

Many thanks,

Comment: no problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue (14 - Oct 20//WooCommerce 4.5.2).  I found that creating a single, simple product as a test rectified the issue.  All my products are now mapped across to the new domain.